# How do I generate “version 3” vanity onion addresses?

Tags: address

How do I generate vanity onion addresses of *the Tor Rendezvous specification **version 3***? *Scallion* does not support it.

---

> ## [Scallion README.md](https://github.com/lachesis/scallion)
>
> **Scallion** was a hobby project to learn OpenCL and RSA. We are not currently maintaining scallion. It has bitrotted in two important ways:
>
> Tor has moved on to [v3 Onion addresses](https://github.com/torproject/torspec/blob/master/rend-spec-v3.txt), which scallion does not support. Old v2 addresses will stop working in October of 2021. The new spec uses different cryptographic primitives and is overall more complicated.

> ## [Types of .onion addresses](https://old.reddit.com/r/onions/wiki/index#wiki_types_of_.onion_addresses)
>
> ### v2 onion services
>
> They will always be 16 characters long. Each character has 32 possible values. Therefore, there are 3216 == 1,208,925,819,614,629,174,706,176 unique v2 onion addresses.
>
> > Example = `facebookcorewwwi.onion`
>
> - The address is "the first 80 bits of the SHA-1 of the 1024-bit RSA key"
>
> ### v3 onion services
>
> They will always be 56 characters long. A v3 address will always end in a `d` due to the way v3 onion service names are encoded.
>
> > Example = `vww6ybal4bd7szmgncyruucpgfkqahzddi37ktceo3ah7ngmcopnpyyd.onion`
>
> Some reasons for the update to move from v2 onions:
>
> - The cryptographic building blocks use updated or more secure signature algorithms and hashing methods. For instance, the older SHA1/DH/RSA1024 was swapped with SHA3/ed25519/curve25519.
> - Directory protocol has been improved and now leaks less metadata to directory servers. This is, in part, to avoid attacks where a hidden service can be censored easily based on the descriptor. To prevent predictability Tor uses, different, pseudo random variables. Time period, public keys, shared random values, etc.
> - “Better onion address security against impersonation; more extensible introduction/rendezvous protocol; and a cleaner and more modular codebase.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [mkp224o](https://github.com/cathugger/mkp224o) to generate V3 onion addresses.

Comment: Love mkp224o, been running it all out for a month on my raspberry pi 4. I strongly recomend using a filter list text file if you want to find longer names, then you can be looking for many things at once. My filter has a few hundred ideas in it. 5 character names drop several per hour, each character you add to it takes about 25x longer to find

Comment: @DavesPlanet I use old AMD Phenom II 1090T (limited to 2 cores), it can found 5 characters onion address in just 1 second. And it can found 6 characters onion address in about 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

After installing [mkp224o](https://github.com/cathugger/mkp224o), use it as:
`mkp224o -B YOUR_PREFIX`

Alternately, you can use [tor-v3-vanity](https://github.com/dr-bonez/tor-v3-vanity) for employing **GPU** to speed up finding addresses.